# how can i find information about all exchange server in the organization?

Tags: exchange-2007, powershell

Power Shell command Get-mailbox gives details of all the mailboxes on the server by which i am running this command. For example, i have two exchange server in my organization named server1 and server2.

Currently i am using exchange management shell on the server named server1 . On this server, if i am running command get-mailbox , this gives me details of all the mailboxes on that server i.e. on server1, but i wants to know details of all the mailboxes on exchange server named server2  by using exchange management shell on server1 i.e. without using server2. Is it possible or not?

if yes, then please mention how?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Get-Mailbox -Server server2
```

or

```
Get-ExchangeServer | Get-Mailbox
```

to get mailboxes from all servers in your organisation.